# How to place checkboxes in the same row?

Tags: python

[image]

Everyone, I want to arrange the checkboxes horizontally like this, what should I do? I tried some methods but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: Hello and welcome to the site! As of now your question contains very little information and is hard to answer (though the image is a good start!). Please elaborate a bit, especially concerning which methods you have already tried.

Comment: Maybe you can drag and drop it!!

Answer (score 1):

You need to split your layout or column or whatever with `split()` method.

```
def draw(self, context):
    layout = self.layout()
    props = context.scene.my_props # your properties
    col = layout.split()
    col.prop(props, "x_axis") # your property name
    col.prop(props, "y_axis") # your property name
    col.prop(props, "z_axis") # your property name
```

[More on UI Layout](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.UILayout.html)

Comment: Ok, thank you for your answer :)